# Consuming a json API on different domain

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an an ember app *for demo purposes* (important to note, as some of what I'm doing here is not secure/best practice). I have no back end and am publishing it on github pages (the purpose is to show Ember, not Rails or whatever other backend I might write).

The data this app is displaying is mostly from a public api (the [Riot api](http://developer.riotgames.com/) if it matters]). I'll get my data from there quite easily, but obviously I can't modify and save it or anything. To that end, I set up a RESTAdapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://prod.api.pvp.net',

    namespace: 'api/lol/na/v1.3',

    buildURL: function (x, y) {
        var url = this._super(x, y);

        return url + '?api_key=<my_api_key_here :)>';
    }    
});
```

I was somewhat surprised to see this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

It had built the url string correctly, but the request to their api failed. I googled around for quite awhile and discovered this is a common sense restriction by them to prevent cross-site abuse of the api or some such, and also to prevent javascript apps (such as mine!) from doing exactly what I was doing. Please note that *I'm aware of why I shouldn't do this, and wouldn't if this were in any way a production app*. Since it's just for my own ends, I figured I would be okay leaving my api key in the javascript and doing it this way, if only I could figure out a way around this error.

---

## Why I was surprised it didn't work

I'm surprised because previous to using Ember data and the REST Adapter, I was loading models from this exact api with simple ajax promises, and it worked like a charm. Doing the following **worked**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/summoner/<some id>?api_key=<my_api_key>',
    success: function (modelJson) {
        store.createRecord('summoner', modelJson); //or somehing
    }
});
```

Why should this work, while whatever the REST Adapter is trying to do isn't? Either way the request is coming from my framework right? How can I get Ember Data to request its data more closely to the above, which I know works?

---

## Something else I tried

It's worth noting I tried the following initializer:

```
    initialize: function () {
        Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
            options.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
        });
    }
```

The error message changes to `A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.`